# What do i need to do to make bubbleSort() modify array values globally?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, global

This code may look really bad, i am a beginner program so tips to make my code better will help a lot. I was wondering how to make bubbleSort() modify array values globally?, at the moment I fill up my array in main, and it works into the search methods, but then i use bubbleSort() and then try and do the searches and it seems bubbleSort() didn't affect the array in main, but only kept it in the function. I have been looking around, and places say i need to malloc, if so how would i modify my code to be able to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
   char name[10][9];
   int data[10];
}Word;

void bubbleSort (Word q);
void linearSearch(int num, Word q);
void binarySearch(int num, Word q);

int main (int argc, const char *argv[]){
    Word q;
    char txtName[9];  /* One extra for nul char. */
    int score;
    int i = 0;
    int m = 0;
    FILE *ifp, *ofp;
    ifp = fopen("Data.txt", "r");
    while (fscanf(ifp, "%8s %d", txtName, &score) == 2) {
        strcpy(q.name[i], txtName);
        printf ("Name: %s \n", q.name[i], i);
        q.data[i] = score;
        printf ("Data: %d \n", q.data[i], i);
        i++;
    }
    linearSearch(320, q);
    binarySearch(320, q);
    bubbleSort(q);
    while (m <= 9){
        printf("Name: %s, Data: %d \n", q.name[m], q.data[m]);
        m++;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
void linearSearch(int num, Word q){ 
    int i = 0;
    int foundIt = 0; 
    int numNumbers = 10;
    while ((foundIt == 0) && (i <= numNumbers)){
        if (num != q.data[i]){
            i = i + 1;
        } else {
            foundIt = 1;
        }
    }
    if (foundIt == 1){
        printf("Name found at position %d \n", i + 1); 
    } else {
        printf("Required person not found \n"); 
    } 
}

void bubbleSort (Word q){
    int last = 9;
    int Swapped = 1; 
    int i = 0;
    int m = 0;
    char temp[32] = "Hello";
    int tempA;
    while (Swapped == 1){
        Swapped = 0;
        i = 0;
        while (i < last){
            if (q.data[i] > q.data[i+1]) {;
                //Copy Name of Element
                strcpy (temp, q.name[i]);
                strcpy(q.name[i], q.name[i+1]);
                strcpy(q.name[i+1] , temp);

                //Copy Data of corresponding element
                tempA = q.data[i];
                q.data[i] = q.data[i+1];
                q.data[i+1] = tempA;
                Swapped = 1; 

            } 
            i = i + 1;
        }
        last = last - 1;
    }
    linearSearch(320, q);
}

void binarySearch(int num, Word q){
    int Lower = 0;
    int Upper = sizeof(&q.data);
    int FoundIt = 0; 
    int PositionFound;
    int Middle = 0;
    while (FoundIt == 0 || (Lower > Upper) != 0){
        Middle = floor((Upper + Lower) / 2); 
        if (num == q.data[Middle]){
            FoundIt = 1;
            PositionFound = Middle;
        } else {
            if (num < q.data[Middle]){
                Upper = Middle - 1;
            } else {
                Lower = Middle + 1;
            }
        } 
    }   
    if (FoundIt == 1){
        printf("Name found at position %d \n", PositionFound + 1); 
    } else {
        printf("Required person not found \n"); 
    } 
}
```

input is:
John 32
Mark 12
Matthew 29
Luke 21
Issac 24
Kane 2
Ryan 5
Abel 10
Adam 320
Eve 1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bubble Sort in C array swapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426567/bubble-sort-in-c-array-swapping)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Please don't put same question again and again. Follow up the previous one.

Comment: Pass your `Word` instance by pointer. As it is you are passing by value and thus modifying a copy of the `Word` instance you pass in, the original remains unchanged. You don't need a global.

Comment: @SouravGhosh no its a different problem, with the other one i was simply wondering how to swap them so that it affects the struct array globally? and that what i do in bubbleSort i can use that array anywhere else?

Comment: @PaulRooney how do i do that? can you show me how?

Comment: Honestly, your setup from inception is wrong. Each line should be a *single* struct, and dynamic sequence of said-structs along with its magnitude should be the source, and target, of your sort operation.

Comment: @WhozCraig can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: You need to read about this stuff and figure things out for yourself. You need to change the function signature to `void bubbleSort (Word* q)`. When you call it use `bubbleSort(&q);` and inside the function anywhere you use `q.` you need to switch to `q->`. Thats just a starter. There are other issues, but if you read a book or do tutorials you'll be able to recognise them for yourself.

Comment: And why the `i`(3rd argument) in `printf ("Name: %s \n", q.name[i], i) ;`?

Comment: @MatthewSolomonson Example of reading from stdin to a dynamic growing sequence and a traditional bubble-sort can be [seen **here**](http://ideone.com/oI6gT7). It should be obvious how what I said earlier applies. Note the word `strcpy` appears *nowhere* in that code. I leave the searching for you to retro. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a structure, you pass a copy of it. Any changes inside the called function are reflected only in that copy.

You can pass instead the address of the existing structure and, inside the called function, dereference the address to get at its contents.

```
void bubbleSort(Word *pq); // pass address of structure

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     /* ... */
     bubbleSort(&q);
     /* ... */
}

void bubbleSort(Word *pq) {
    /* ... */
    /* use pq->STUFF instead of p.STUFF */
            if (pq->data[i] > pq->data[i + 1]) {
                /* ... */
            }
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to change the array globally, you have to pass word as a pointer ( that is send the address of the array so that whatever change you make inside your function is reflected in your array)

Change your code to this

Function definition

```
void bubbleSort (Word *q);
```

and Function call

```
bubbleSort(&q);
```

and Function Declaration

```
void bubbleSort (Word q)
```